# Snap.js: Initialize with jQuery instead of plain JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, snap.js

How does one initialize Snap.js with jQuery instead of plain JS?

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/5X4K9/11/

JavaScript:

```
var snapper = new Snap({
    element: document.getElementById('content')
});

var addEvent = function addEvent(element, eventName, func) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        return element.addEventListener(eventName, func, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        return element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, func);
    }
};

addEvent(document.getElementById('open-panel'), 'click', function () {
    snapper.open('left');
});
```

jQuery (doesn't work):

```
var snapper = new Snap($("#content")[0]);

$("#open-panel").click(function () {
    snapper.open('left');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the same arguments to the Snap constructor in plain JavaScript and jQuery. Under jQuery, try the following in place of your current constructor call:

```js
var snapper = new Snap({
    element: $("#content")[0]
});
```